# leaflet can not clear layer and marker

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dictionary, web, leaflet

i want to remove all marker s from map and trying to remove markers with map.remove

i am using vue.js with leaflet to show map
i got a object to  record lng and lat

```
router_planning: [
    {
      car: [
        {
          name: "001",
          lat: 25.042474,
          lng: 121.513729,
        },
        {
          name: "002",
          lat: 24.982474,
          lng: 121.613729,
        },
        {
          name: "003",
          lat: 24.894474,
          lng: 121.623729,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      car: [
        {
          name: "004",
          lat: 24.982474,
          lng: 121.513729,
        },
        {
          name: "005",
          lat: 24.882474,
          lng: 121.513729,
        },
        {
          name: "006",
          lat: 24.982474,
          lng: 121.713729,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
```

and two function  below
initmap() //set view

```
initmap() {
  this.mapp = L.map("map");
  this.mapp.setView(
    [
      this.router_planning[0].car[0].lat,
      this.router_planning[0].car[0].lng,
    ],
    10
  ); 
  L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    maxZoom: 13, 
    minZoom: 9,
  }).addTo(this.mapp);
},
```

make_map() //give map marker

```
make_map() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.router_planning.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < this.router_planning[i].car.length; j++) {
      L.circleMarker(
        [
          this.router_planning[i].car[j].lat,
          this.router_planning[i].car[j].lng,
        ],
        {
          color: this.circle_marker[i],
          fillColor: this.circle_marker[i],
          fillOpacity: 1,
          radius: (i + 1) ** 2,
        }
      )
        .addTo(this.mapp)
        .bindTooltip(this.router_planning[i].car[j].name.toString(), {
          permanent: true,
        });

     
  }
},
```

my web should work like this
first initmap()  then make_map()

i got a button to trigger make_map() to change  lat and lng

but old marker didn't disappear

i have tried add

this.mapp.remove() to the top of make_map()
i got error message

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')
```

i have tried add this to top of make_map with no error

but  didnt clear marker

```
var container = L.DomUtil.get('map');
    container._leaflet_id = null;
```

i have watched many article to clear map but still didn't work
it's make me crazy to find out why i can't clear or remove map

thanks alot

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve here? If I understand correctly you want to remove all markers from map and you're trying to remove markers with map.remove()?

Comment: yes u r right i want to remove all marker s from map and trying to remove markers with map.remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove all markers from the map you must first store them somewhere.
You can store all markers inside of an array:

```
const markers = [];

const marker = L.circleMarker([...])
        .bindTooltip([...])
        .addTo(map);
markers.push(marker);
```

And to remove them you need to call:

```
for(let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    map.removeLayer(marker[i]);
}
```

But there's a better way to do it if you don't need to remove specific marker, use `LayerGroup()`.
Example:

```
const layerGroup = new L.LayerGroup();

const marker = new L.marker([...]).addTo(layerGroup);

//after you've added all markers to layerGroup():
map.addLayer(layerGroup)
```

And to remove all markers simply call: `map.removeLayer(layerGroup)`

Comment: thanks a lot i really appreciate it

Comment: @BBQB be sure to mark the answer as accepted if it answers your question. This will let others know with the same question know that this is the answer they are looking for.